# Searching a Text in XML files

Tags: xml, search-engine, pentaho, kettle

I am having many Kettle Transformation saved files (saved in desktop). What i need to do is to create a search page, where in the user types in any text. The result displayed is all the possible transformation saved files where that particular typed string appears.

Note that the transformation files are in XML format. The search string can be anything that an XML file can contain. I have no clue of how to develop this search? Please help me out.

[ I have tried using XPATH to read the xml files (using the Pentaho Data Integration tool), but missing the connection of the search.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I uderstood what you want correctly, try that:

1. In the **properties of you transformation** define a **parameter** "String4Search".
2. You take "**Get Data from XML**" step. To get all the XML files, you should set "**File/Directory**" to your **desktop path**, and the wildcard "**.*.xml**"
   Than you define a field (say named "found_string") which contains the searched string if it presents in file (XPath: **//*[contains(text(),"${String4Search}")]**). You also should check the checkbox "**Include filename in output**" and definde the name of the field which contains the name of the input file.
3. You connect a "**Filter rows**" step  after your "Get Data from XML" step, and there you can **filter all records where the field "found_string" is empty**.
4. Then you just add steps for **selection** of the field with filename, and **removal of  duplicates** and that's your results.

Everytime when you **start the transformation**, you are **asked to set the value** of parameter **"String4Search"**. So you just set it to your string to be found in files.

Answer (score 1):

Kettle is not a search tool.  You're best bet is to just execute grep on these files and read the results back in.

If you were using a database repository then of course you could query the database directly, which is much nicer.

Comment: @Codek : Thanks ... But Suppose if i run a kettle transformation where i take "Get Data from XML" step and get the desired result using appropiate XPATH and output  it in a text file(fr ex.). Finally i run a javascript on the output in the same transformation. Is it possible?